# IOS: gesture for more views

Tags: ios, xcode, gesture, swipe

I have this code:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
[recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[view1 addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[view2 addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[view3 addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];

- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{ //do something}
```

it recognizes swipe only in view3, why? and how can I solve this problem? Should I do a new swipegesture for every views? but I have 20 views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 20 views, they might be stored in an array or something? If yes, have you tried something like this?

```
 for (unsigned i = 0; i < [yourViewsArray count]; i++){
    UIView *view = [yourViewsArray objectAtIndex:i]; 
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
    [recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
 }
```

With this you add a new recognizer to every view

Comment: my fault, i will edit that, anyway you could set up a gesturerecognizer for all views like that